# Sum all the numbers between two indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

My 1x500 matrix consist of numbers, I want to sum all the numbers between two indices, lets say between 100 and 300. Forgot how to do that, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have the matrix:

```
m = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

and indices:

```
idx1 = 3;
idx2 = 6;
```

Getting the sum is easy:

```
sum(m(idx1:idx2))
```

So the answer to your question is:

```
ans = sum(your_m1x500(100:300));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)